# How to setup MQTT tests in SoapUI opensource version?

Tags: soapui

SoapUI release notes said that it supports MQTT tests now. It is also backed by this official page: https://www.soapui.org/enterprise/soapui-ng-pro/soapui-vs-soapui-ng-pro.html

But I was not able to start using the supposedly bundled plugin, is it restricted to Ready Api only? If it is not, how do I start?

Comment: What do you mean by "not able start using supposedly bundled plugin"?

Comment: @Rao thanks for replying, this official page (https://www.soapui.org/extension-plugins/bundled.html) says that MQTT plugin was already bundled as of 5.2.0 release (mine is 5.2.1), so I assume it was bundled in already. But I could not find any menu options/settings to start setting up an MQTT test, all I was able to was create SOAP or REST tests. :(

Comment: Then why not try in 5.2.0 and see?

Comment: The reason being that if you see the log files, there might be errors loading plugin, so you not able to see the respective plugin. So, try in 5.2.

Comment: @Rao Thanks, it seems I should be looking at adding test step using MQTT directly, rather than building a resource like the REST requests. :)